# Ajax Add to cart in wishlist page magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, addtocart, ajax, magento2.4

I'm looking for a way to add ajax functionality to the wishlist page. So when I add a product to the cart in my wishlist page it utilizes ajax.

How would I approach this?

Hope for an answer. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which theme you are using? and does that theme have ajax add to cart into there?

Comment: Athlete2. Yes it does. But this does not include the wishlist page.